# Getting Class type from String

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have a `String` which has a name of a class say `"Ex"` (no `.class` extension). I want to assign it to a `Class` variable, like this:

```
Class cls = (string).class
```

How can i do that?

Comment: what if the class is in different project?

Comment: To your comment:  What!???

If your class was in a different project, then wouldn't it depend on your IDE?  As far as your application is concerned, it would be as though it was in the same project anyways because it's libraries are referenced externally.  Like, you know that the the Java API classes are not in your project, right?  But, the compiler for your IDE knows where to find them, if your IDE is set up correctly.  The same applies to your classes from another project.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
```

But your `className` should be fully-qualified - i.e. `com.mycompany.MyClass`

Comment: its throwing ClassNotFound Exception

Comment: then either the class is not on the classpath or you are not passing the fully qualified class name e.g. com.mycompany.project.ClassName

Comment: what value of `className` are you passing? Is there such a class on your classpath?

Comment: yeah the Class is in same package

Comment: @Steven - why do you pass as an argument? `MyClassName` or `com.mypackage.MyClassName` ?

Comment: what if class is in different project?

Comment: "project" isn't a term in java-runtime. If you mean "jar" or "archive", then - if the jar is on the classpath, it will work fine.

Comment: @Steven if you want to run this in an IDE with dependent project, tell us your IDE.

Comment: To get the full class name use:-
classname.getClass().getName() instead of classname.getClass().toString().

I was doing this mistake for same exception.

Comment: I got the same problem with `ClassNotFoundException`. The trick was to handle the exception in a try-catch. Something like this: `try { Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.company.MyClass"); } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { /* do something to handle the case when the string isn't valid and therefor the class can't be found */ }`

Comment: What part/function of the java SDK would this type of functionality be under, reflection?

Answer (score 46):

```
String clsName = "Ex";  // use fully qualified name
Class cls = Class.forName(clsName);
Object clsInstance = (Object) cls.newInstance();
```

Check the Java Tutorial trail on Reflection at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/TOC.html for further details.

Comment: Bozho's answer might have more points, but I think that yours is more descriptive.


PS.  Why is your name JuanZe???  Almost sounds like a mix between Spanish and Chinese.  :D.  Is there some sort of clever meaning behind it?

Comment: I'm working with a Dynamic web project in eclipse. I am using above code to fetch a Class. but it returns ClassNotFoundException, when I use a string variable like this:

`String clsName = "com.mydoamin.className";
Class cls = Class.forName(clsName);`





If is hardcode the fully qualified class name as the parameter then things work fine. Any suggestion?

Comment: @JuanZe I came across this answer while searching for something else and now I am curious... What can one do with such a conversion?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `forName` method of `Class`:

```
Class cls = Class.forName(clsName);
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
```

Comment: I'm working with a Dynamic web project in eclipse. I am using above code to fetch a Class. but it returns ClassNotFoundException, when I use a string variable like this:

`String clsName = "com.mydoamin.className";
Class cls = Class.forName(clsName);`





If is hardcode the fully qualified class name as the parameter then things work fine. Any suggestion?

Comment: @djthequest If our `clsName` variable contains the fully qualified classname there should be no difference between using it and the hardcoded string. You might not have the class you need in the classpath. It might help to instantiate a common class from the same jar in your startup code to make sure the library is present in the classloader.

Comment: thanks for your response, but instead of the variable if I hardcode the string, works fins, it means the classes are in class path, right? Later i figured out, `Class.forName()` method expects a `final` variable. A simple variable won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the Class reference of any class during run time through the Java Reflection Concept.

Check the Below Code. Explanation is given below

Here is one example that uses returned Class to create an instance of AClass:

```
package com.xyzws;
class AClass {
    public AClass() {
        System.out.println("AClass's Constructor"); 
    }  
    static {   
        System.out.println("static block in AClass");  
    }
}
public class Program {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {       
            System.out.println("The first time calls forName:");   
            Class c = Class.forName("com.xyzws.AClass");      
            AClass a = (AClass)c.newInstance();    
            System.out.println("The second time calls forName:");  
            Class c1 = Class.forName("com.xyzws.AClass"); 
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
            // ...
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {  
            // ...
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { 
            // ...
        }     
    }
}
```

The printed output is

```
    The first time calls forName:
    static block in AClass
    AClass's Constructor
    The second time calls forName:
```

The class has already been loaded so there is no second "static block in AClass"

***The Explanation is below***

Class.ForName is called to get a Class Object

By Using the Class Object we are creating the new instance of the Class.

Any doubts about this let me know

Comment: what if class is in different project?

Comment: Can you get a jar file of that proect and specify the class name
some thing like 
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

`Class.forName(String classname)`

Comment: Can you also do this for Subclasses?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking, but... [Class.forname](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29), maybe?

Comment: its throwing ClassNotFound Exception

Comment: what if class is in different project?

Comment: I see that no one is answering your question.  It shouldn't matter if it's in another project as long as the compiler knows where to look.  Since, you're probably using an IDE, it probably depends solely on the IDE.

The thing about references, you know that all of the classes that you reference from the Java libraries are not in your project, right?  But, the compiler knows where to look for them because it knows that they're referenced externally.

It seems that you need to learn basic Java programming when you're attempting to advanced Java programming.  :|

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Class<?> getType(String typeName) {
    if(typeName.equals("Date")) {
      return Date.class;
    } else if(typeName.equals("Float")) {
      return Float.class;
    } else if(typeName.equals("Double")) {
      return Double.class;
    } else if(typeName.equals("Integer")) {
      return Integer.class;
    }
    return String.class;
}
```