# JAVA - cast using class obtained by its name (string value)

Tags: java, class, reflection, casting

this is what my code looks if I use a predefined class:

```
List<MyClass> result = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
try {
    Query query = mgr.newQuery(MyClass.class);
    for(Object obj : (List<Object>) query.execute()) {
        result.add(((MyClass) obj));
    }
}
.... 
return result;
```

now I need to be more generic: starting from a generic class name (as a string,  ie "TheChosenOne") I need to do the same thing, but I can't figure out how the cast part should be done..

Just to make an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
String str = "TheChosenOne"; //this value may change
Class cls;
List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
try {
    if(str.equals("TheChosenOne"))
        cls = Class.forName("com.blabla.TheChosenOne");
    else if(str.equals("Rabbit"))
        cls = Class.forName("com.blabla.Rabbit");
    else if(str.equals("Batman"))
        cls = Class.forName("com.heroes.Batman");
    else
        cls = null;

    if(cls != null){
        Query query = mgr.newQuery(MyClass.class);
        for(Object obj : (List<Object>) query.execute()) {
            result.add(((???) obj)); //I need help here!
        }
    }
}
...
return result;
```

I took the "Class.forName()..." part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408789/getting-class-type-from-string).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you are trying to do is unnecessary because your list is declared as `List<Object>` so the cast is not needed.

-- Before Edit --

Not sure I understand what you need, but did you try to use:

```
Class.cast(object)
```

This is a method of the java.lang.Class

Comment: `result.add((Class.cast(obj)))` is the same as `result.add(obj)`. Because list is of type Object

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved with generics.

For example a method like this:

```
     public <E> List<E> getList(Class<E> clazz) {
         List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
         if(clazz != null){
             Query query = mgr.newQuery(MyClass.class);
             for(E obj : (List<E>)query.execute()) {
                 result.add(obj); 
             }
         }

         return result;
     }
```

Can be called with:

```
 getList(TheChosenOne.class)
```

And it will return a `List<TheChosenOne>` object

Answer (score 2):

If `result` is a `List<Object>` then you don't need a cast at all, simply `add(obj)` will work fine.

If you need compile time type safety then you will have to pass in the `Class` object rather than a string containing its name, and use a generic method signature

```
public <T> List<T> doQuery(Class<T> theClass) {
  List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
  try {
    Query query = mgr.newQuery(theClass);
    for(T obj : (List<T>) query.execute()) {
      result.add(obj);
    }
  }
  .... 
  return result;
}
```

If you go this route, and have the option of modifying the `Query` class then you might want to consider making that class parameterized

```
public class Query<E> {
  public List<E> execute() { ... }
}

// and in mgr
public <T> Query<T> newQuery(Class<T> cls)
```

which would then let you say

```
    Query<T> query = mgr.newQuery(theClass);
    for(T obj : query.execute()) {
      result.add(obj);
```

with no casting at all.

Comment: I need to return a list of TheChosenOne class, or a list of Rabbit class or a list of Batman class, based on the value of the str string..

Answer (score 0):

I believe `cls.cast(obj)` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it in this way: using `instance of` operator to check the type of the class and then do the type casting

```
for(Object obj : (List<Object>) query.execute()) {
  if(obj instance of Batman)
    result.add(((Batman) obj));
  else if(obj instance of Cat)
    result.add(((Cat) obj));

  // and so on
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need cast while putting object in the ArrayList,

```
 result.add(obj);
```

If you want you can cast while getting from the list

```
 cls .cast(result.get(1));
```