# How do I use a String as a reference to a Class using reflection?

Tags: java, string, class, reflection, invoke

I'm building a String parser that parses a file, gets stuff, and does stuff with the stuff. Mainly, I am trying to reference classes from that file. If that file had some text:

"Class1"

How could I interpret the String as a Class within the program to then invoke a method?

Comment: Well do you know which class declares the method? Look at the documentation for `Class.getDeclaredMethods` etc.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: the question has now changed. not a duplicate anymore!

Comment: Way to change the question completely. (Don't forget your title.) It is now a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408789/getting-class-type-from-string