# Convert a String into a class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent

I have a string called `theClass`. It contains a string which is `.class`. I want to put that string into the second parameter of my intent; I know this isn't possible, but how can I use my string, which is a class, in an intent?

For example, if String theClass was:

```
String theClass = "anotherClassInMyProj.class";
```

I cannot do something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, theClass);
```

How would I use the string as a class then? Would I need to convert it somehow, and are there built in methods to do so?

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408789/getting-class-type-from-string)

Comment: You can have intent which takes `className` as string. Use `intent.setClassName(packageContext, className)` where `className` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    String className = "com.example.anotherClassInMyProj";
    Intent startfunction = new Intent();
    startfunction.setClassName(getPackageName().toString(), classname);
    startActivity(startfunction);
```

Comment: Why does the className have com.example

Comment: Class name with package (Fully Qualified Class name)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use:

```
String theClass = "anotherClassInMyProj.class"
Class c=Class.forName(theClass);
```

Comment: will `Class.forName` work? `theClass` have `.class` in the end?

Comment: Why are we doing Class.forName?  Also, similar to OAD's question, does the c object contain a .class at the end? Or do we have to remove the .class in String theClass for it to work?  I will mark this best answer and hit the like button after I get these questions answered. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i= new Intent(this,Class.forName(theClass);
```

Comment: will `Class.forName` work? `theClass` have `.class` in the end? forName need qualified name.

Comment: you need to remove .class, you may use regex for that , and you have to handle classnotfound exception.

Comment: exactly thats what i m trying so say, add this in your ans.

Comment: @OAD So basically, if I take out the .class from String theClass, it will work? If so, does what does method forName do, and why are we putting Class. instead of .Class? Sorry for all the questions, but this is a very interesting topic to understand. I will mark this best answer and hit the like button after I get these questions answered. Thanks so much!