# Generic type declaration from string

Tags: java, string, generics, instantiation

I have a Class TestClass{}
I need to create instance for this class from string input

```
TestClass<"StringValue"> obj = new TestClass<"StringValue">()
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can't . The compiler makes these checks. I am not sure if there is a way to hoodwink it

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Longer answer: You probably don't need to. Please tell us what you actually want to do.

Comment: That stringvalue will be some other classname..is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defenitely misunderstand purpose of generics in Java. Shortly, generics enables *types* to be parameters, but not exact values. [Take a look at documentation to get more.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) Quote from this article:

> In a nutshell, generics enable types (classes and interfaces) to be parameters when defining classes, interfaces and methods. Much like the more familiar formal parameters used in method declarations, type parameters provide a way for you to re-use the same code with different inputs. The difference is that the inputs to formal parameters are values, while the inputs to type parameters are types.

If you want to define some specific value during class instantiation, [pass it to constructor as parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

### UPDATE:

OP pointed out that string value he mentioned in original question is string representation of class name. In this case generics won't help because Java generics are only compile-time feature and you can't parametrize class with value calculated in runtime. You can create `Class` instance from it's name as it's described in this question: [Getting Class type from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408789/getting-class-type-from-string), but it still could not be used as generics parameter.

Comment: My string value can be "Integer","String","Float".. eg : I need like this TestClass<Integer> obj = TestClass<Integer>;

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done, string "" and all primitive data type like `int` `double` etc cannot be used in generic.

But you can do like this:

`Foo<String>` or `Foo<Integer>` etc ...

If this cannot satisfy your needs, then you can create a class and store all data that you need, just like below:

```
public class Foo {
    String stringValue;
    int intValue;
    ...
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public TestClass<Foo> {
   ...
}
```

**Updated:**

You also can put the data as `String` then you can parse it to any other type of data, like `int`, `float` etc.

For example:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("12");

int intValue = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..I wanted to do like this   class:  SinglyLinkedList<T>{T item;} .   object type:  SinglyLinkedList<Integer or String or Any type> obj;  ...That type is selected from a combo box ..I am geting that required classname as a string...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to do,

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(classnameAsString);

clazz.newInstance(); // created object from name of class
```

Revisited my old questions :P .Thanks for other answers that introduced me few other things in Java :)