# forName returned value as Type

Tags: java, reflection

Can I use Class value returned by Class.forName as a type ?

e.g.

```
String hdrClassName = "generated.MessageHeader";
Class msgHdrClass= Class.forName(hdrClassName);
JAXBElement<msgHdrClass> jaxbWrapperElement1 = (JAXBElement<msgHadrClass>)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("./src/MessageHeader.xml"));
```

If not, Is there a way to achieve "using class name passed at run time as type in java"?

Comment: What would be the point of that? Generic in Java are to enable more complex higher-order *compile time* type system. Generic types only exist at compile time and are only useful if you know the type at compile time. If you know that your msgHdrClass always extends a particular class or interface, then you can use constructs like `JAXElement<? extends MySuperType>` or simply `JAXBEle,emt<MySuperType>` as applicable.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408789/getting-class-type-from-string

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You should post it as an answer.