# Create a new object by using string as class name

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert a string to class name to use like the code above (I tried to use Class.forName but it didn't work)

```
Class c = Class.forName("SportCar");
c car= new c();     
System.out.println(car.getCost());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Car car = (Car) clazz.newInstance();
```

If you have a some parameterized constructor in the class then do something like

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
clazz.newInstance();
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class); 
Car object = (Car) constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { someArgument}); // constructor args
```

Answer (score 2):

You need call to `newInstance` method:

```
Class<SportCar> c = (Class<SportCar>) Class.forName("package.to.SoprtCar");
SportCar car = c.newInstance();     
System.out.println(car);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Getting Class type from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408789/getting-class-type-from-string)

make sure that you have the full class name like com.mycompany.MyClass when using the for Name Methdo

Comment: If you mark question as duplicate don't post the link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Object having the class name `SportCar`. Though it is a very costly way for object creation, using reflection.

And *in fact* you want to use some features of `SportCar`, namely the method `getCost`.

```
interface Costly { BigDecimal getCost(); }

class SportCar implements Costly { ... }

Class c = Class.forName("SportCar");
Costly car= (Costly) c.newInstance();     
System.out.println(car.getCost());
```

There are better, less artificial code patterns for a couple of different use cases.

Here one could use a **factory pattern** to receive a SportCar (or Costly).
For **extendability**, where an application with the addition of one or more libraries of still unknown classes receives an implementation class of some interface, java **SPI (service provider interface)** can be used.