# How to get methods in java?

Tags: java, integration-testing, mockmvc

I want to get methods for all classes in java. I try to this ;
I have a XIT test class in my project.

```
private List<String> getTestNames() {
      
        Method[] methods = XIT.class.getMethods();
        List<String> listMethods = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());
                listMethods.add(method.getName());
            }
        }
        return listMethods;
    }
```

I get test methods for X class but I want to this for another classes in same method. What should I do?

```
Method[] methods = XClass.class.getMethods();
```

I want to remove XIT, I have alot of IT test classes in my project and I want to give parameter for each entity and run for all *IT classes:

```
private List<String> getTestNames(String entityname) {
        String fullentity = (entityname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.US) + entityname.substring(1) );+ "IT"
        Method[] methods = **fullentity**.class.getMethods();
        List<String> listMethods = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class) ) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());
                listMethods.add(method.getName());
            }
        }
        return listMethods;
    }
```

but fullentity does not Class and I have an error Unknown class for fullentity. How do I convert class for each entity or What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Class type from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408789/getting-class-type-from-string)

Comment: Well, if you have the fully qualified class name you could use `Class.forName(fqcn)` otherwise you might need to scan the classpath for classes that match certain criteria (how to do the scan depends on what frameworks/libraries you have available).

Comment: Try with `Class.forName(className)`. Class name must be fully qualified (ie with package name)

Comment: I updated with this and I still give same error
 Class fullentity =Class.forName(entityname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.US) + entityname.substring(1)+ "IT" );
        Object obj = (Object) fullentity.newInstance();
        Method[] methods = obj.class.getMethods();

Comment: But I have systems.bael.controller.sale.XIT, systems.bael.controller.res.YIT, systems.bael.controller.ask.ZIT etc. and I have alot of test class. How do I for multiple packages for fully name? @Jayr

Comment: Hi @butd, I think you might be trying to do what a test suite is already doing. Also in maven as long as the tests are saved under src/test/java all methods annotated by Test will be run. If somehow you still need to scan the Tests yourself, you have no choice but to specify the FQCN. You will need to catch that class not found exception, if the package didn't match systems.bael.controller.ask or systems.bael.controller.res etc